# C++ same namespace issue

Tags: c++

There is `std` namespace in `<iostream>` and `<cmath>`. And it has same function named `sinh`, etc. But it is different with parameter and return type.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

typedef std::function<double(double)> HyperbolicFn;

std::vector<HyperbolicFn> fns = {
  std::sinh, std::cosh, std::tanh
};

auto main(void) -> int {
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it.

> $ clang -c test.cpp

the compiler message like below.

```
test.cpp:8:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<HyperbolicFn>'
      (aka 'vector<function<double (double)> >')
std::vector<HyperbolicFn> fns = {
                          ^     ~
```

In `<cmath>` header includes `double sinh(double)` function. But `<iostream>` (`<complex>`) doesn't.

How can I solve this? I want to use this code with functions in `<cmath>` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sinh` and the others are overloaded and `std::function` don't play well with overloads it cannot distinguish them. You can do explicit cast

```
using Hyper = double(*)(double);

std::vector<HyperbolicFn> fns = {
    static_cast<Hyper>(std::sinh),
    static_cast<Hyper>(std::cosh),
    static_cast<Hyper>(std::tanh)
};
```

or use lambda instead

```
std::vector<HyperbolicFn> fns = {
    [](double a) { return std::sinh(a); },
    [](double a) { return std::cosh(a); },
    [](double a) { return std::tanh(a); }
};
```

Comment: Wow, it works well. Thanks a lot. I'll do explicit cast.

Comment: In the first form, can also consider using `HyperbolicFn(std::sinh)`, etc instead of `static_cast`s.    This actually is consistent with fact of constructing a `std::function` from the function pointer/name.    One advantage of the second form is ability to generalise better (e.g.  not specifically limited to wrapping functions that only accept one argument).